# Illegal escape character in grails 2.x

Tags: regex, grails-2.0

I was developed one application using grails 1.3.7 version. where i was using regex expression for password validation.

like..

```
 public static final String MYFAX_PASSWORD_REGEX_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%^&*()<>{};:.\\]\\[]{4,20}"
```

and it's working fine but when i am upgrading this project into grails 2.x then its' display me below compilation error.

Can anybody help me?

```
illegal escape character
public static final java.lang.String MYFAX_PASSWORD_REGEX_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()<>{};:.\]\[]{4,20}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Groovy `~"pattern"` expression:

```
def MYFAX_PASSWORD_REGEX_PATTERN = ~/[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()<>{};:.\]\[]{4,20}/
```

For more information refer to the [Groovy Regular Expressions manual](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions).

Comment: Hi Benoit, Thanks now it's compile very well but i am getting other issues.I didn't idea these one related this regex validation or not. But any how thanks for given solution.

Answer (score 1):

The $ is used to put expressions inside a GString.
So you should escape it `\$`

Comment: does this apply for @ too? because I am hving trouble? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776642/regexp-resulting-different-matches-when-run-from-js-file-and-chrome-console