# regexp resulting different matches when run from js file and chrome console

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

This is weird, I have this statement in js code:

```
alert ( "Hello @name , your account will be activated at  @date".match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g) );
```

When I run the code from the file (opening the file using browser) 
I get

```
[hello,name,your,account,be,activated,date]
```

But when I run it on the ***chrome developer console***
I get:

```
[@name,@date]
```

*what is happening here? same code d/t result*

**update:**

As @*funkwurm* tried to mention on the comment there is a change on the code when I inspect the page using chrome developer tool.
`match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g)` was changed to `match(/\[\w_]+/g)`

I am using **Grails** framework so I thought using the *slashy syntax* (/ /) was causing the problem because Grails also uses that syntax ( due to conflict).

so changed it to

```
var pattern = new RegExp("@{1}[\\w_]+","g");    


alert ( "Hello @name , your account will be activated at @date".match(pattern) );
```

but still no effect, and when I do `alert(pattern)` I get `/\[\w_]+/g` still without the @.

**Thanks**

Comment: Which output do you think is correct? What you're seeing in the dev console is what I'd expect to see with that regex. I can't explain why you'd ever get the output with every word. (By the way, `\w` matches underscore characters so you don't need the `_` in your regex. And having `{1}` after the @ is redundant.)

Comment: Are you sure the regex in the file contains the "@" symbol? Have you tried seeing what happens in JSFiddle? The console is correct.

Comment: Incidentally, the regular expression you have simplifies to: `/@\w+/g` ({1} is superfluous, and \w already matches underscores).  Console is correct.  I would definitely bet that your file is ignoring the @ symbols, perhaps they're being processed by some other component?  What does the script contain according to chrome's developer tools? (In the elements tab)

Comment: u may use this `/\@{1}[\w_]+/g` . it may give u same result..

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to the second one (from the console) and thank you for the tips.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski thanks but I see same thing on the elements tab of developer tools

Comment: Something else is going on, if I save this to a file and run it I get the 2nd result. Are you editing a file of a different version of your script than the html-file is loading with `<script src="..."></script>`? Case of die hard cache? Delete your browser history and try again. Change to `alert('hello there?!')` and see if you actually get `hello there?!` or still the regex. I do stupid stuff like this sometimes :P

Comment: @funkwurm may be you are right something else is happening. I tried yours and still get `[hello,there]`

Comment: You're saying the literal code `alert('hello there?!')` gives you `[hello,there]`? Have you prototyped the `alert()` function into doing something else? Post more of the code surrounding it.

Comment: I put this code in new file and I get `null` which is right. `<script>

alert("hello there?!".match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g));

</script>` I dont know what is happening to my code.

Comment: `alert('hello there?!')` is not `alert("hello there?!".match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g));` and `hello there?!` doesn't contain anything starting with a `@`, therefor the match returns `null`. So this makes total sense to me.

Comment: @funkwurm sorry I mean alert("hello there?!".match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g));

Comment: @funkwurm you were right the file was gettting modified. `match(/@{1}[\w_]+/g)` was changed to `match(/\[\w_]+/g)` but dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried to mention on the **update** *the problem was the @ character was missing when inspecting it using chrome developer tool* ( Thanks *@Lee Kowalkowski* for the insight).

I tried ***escaping*** it but still did not work.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(64)+"{1}[\\w_]+","g"); //64 is ascii value of @
```

**Still eager to know why @ character was missing**